# WPF: Binding commands in styles and/or data templates (MVVM)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, styles

Here's the very quick and simplified explanation of my situation. I have defined a style for `Hyperlink` controls and they have `Command` property binded to the command defined in a `ViewModel` class (simplified):

```
<Window.Resources>
  ...
  <Style x:Key="hyperlinkStyle" TargetType="Hyperlink">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=OpenHyperlinkCommand}" />
    ...
  </Style>
  ...
</Window.Resources>
```

Next, I created a content control in the window I am designing. It has a data template defined, written in the window resources. Inside that data template, I added some hyperlinks and I set those hyperlinks to use the previously defined style.

The window looks like this (simplified):

```
<Window>
  ...
  <ContentControl 
      ...
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}" />
  ...
</Window>
```

The data template looks like this (simplified):

```
<Window.Resources>
  ...
  <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:MyType}">
    ...
    <TextBlock>
      <Hyperlink 
          Style="{StaticResource hyperlinkStyle}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Uri1}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Uri1}" />
      </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
    ...
    <TextBlock>
      <Hyperlink 
          Style="{StaticResource hyperlinkStyle}" 
          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Uri2}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Uri2}" />
      </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
    ...
  </DataTemplate>
  ...
</Window.Resources>
```

The binding to the `OpenHyperlinkCommand` in the style doesn't work because the `ViewModel` of the window bound to it contains this command, but the `DataTemplate` is bound to the `MyType` objects, which do not contain this command (nor should).

How should I make this binding work? Two questions:

1. Here's my proposal: I named my window `x:Name="myWindow"`, and changed the binding of 
   the command inside the style to this:

   ```
   <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ElementName=myWindow Path=DataContext.OpenHyperlinkCommand}" />
   ```

   This works, but it looks so dirty. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way, more 
   MVVM-like? This is fragile because I am setting specific element name inside a style!
2. Is it a good practice to write the command bindings inside of a style in the first 
   place? If not, what is the alternative? What if I developed a complex `UserControl`, 
   how would I set commands to components somewhere deep inside its logical tree?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. An alternative syntax would use RelativeSource

   `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenHyperlinkCommand, 
           RelativeSource={Relative Source AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">`
2. I don't see anything wrong with writing command bindings in a style